# Periodicity of states in Markov Chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning

> Determine the classes and the periodicity of the various states for a
>   Markov Chain with transition probability matrix
>   $$P=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0\\\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&0\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm not so sure, but from what I'm understand to find the classes of states, is enough see which states communicate each other, so I think that classes are {0}, {1,2}, {3}.

I looked in my book, and I saw that in some instance they just did the decomposition of matrix in blocks, though I did not understand the logic behind such decomposition, someone explain to me how this is done?

Proceeding, I know that if $i\leftrightarrow j$ then $d(i)=d(j)$ where $d$ denote the period of state. Then I just need to find the periods of state $i=0,1,3$, in the book they say

> We define the period of state $i$, written $d(i)$, to be the greatest
>   common divisor (g.c.d) of all integers $n\geq 1$ for which
>   $P_{ii}^n>0$

I looked this definition several times, but I still do not understand how to apply it, how can I do this?

Comment: Why do you think 0 is its own class separate from 1 and 2?

Notice that for example in state 0, I can get there with positive probability by going there in 2 steps (0 --> 2 --> 0) or in 3 steps (0 --> 2 ---> 1 ---> 0). Thus the gcd is automatically 1 so the period of state 0 must be 1.

Comment: @Brenton I guess I'm confused with the definition of communicative states

Comment: Think of communicative classes as a set of states that you have a positive probability of starting in any one of those states and getting to any other and back. So in your example, let C1 = {0,1,2} is one class because I can start at any one of those states and get to any other in the set, AND BACK to where I began. If you consider C2 =  {3}, you can  move from C2 to C1 if you start in C2, but you can never go back to state 3. Thus, 3 must be a different "class" because you can't get back with positive probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the states are $0,1,2$, and $3$, we see the system can take the paths
$$0 \to 2 \to 0,$$
$$0 \to 2 \to 1 \to 0,$$

so $\{0,1,2\}$ is a communication class with period $\gcd(2,3) = 1$. State 3 does not have a period since the probability of ever reaching 3 is 0.

Comment: You know how to separate classes without the diagram?

Comment: Two states are in the same communication class if and only if there is a finite path between them. I have exhibited a loop $0 \to 2 \to 1 \to 0$, so starting at any of these states, it is possible to get to the other. Although it is possible to go from state 3 to another state, it is impossible to reach state 3, so it is not in the communication class.

Comment: What I was asking is if you know how to separate the classes just looking the matrix.

Comment: Yes, this is how to do it normally. Starting at 0, with probability 1 we see that we go to state 2. Now starting at state 2, we have an equal chance of going to either 0 or 1 (see row two and that the first two elements are 1/2 and 1/2). If we went to 1, then we *must* go back to 0 (the first element of row 1 is 1). Now that we are back at 0, the chain starts again. The transition matrix is a fascinating result from two key properties of the most basic finite Markov chains -- time homogeneity and the Markov property.

Comment: What book are you using for self-study? I just finished a course using "Introduction to Stochastic Processes" by Gregory Lawler, and I found it extremely readable. No measure theory, and the proofs are light.

Comment: I'm using "A first course in stochastic processes, Karlin & Taylor"